# To install GNU Strings in OSX

Tags: macos, homebrew, install

I run unsuccessfully `brew search strings` giving only `Caskroom/cask/stringsfile`.

I want to run this commmand `strings -td -3 <file.raw`.

How can you install GNU Strings in OSX?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run

```
brew install binutils
```

which install binary tools of GNU, which `strings` is a part of.

Comment: May need to follow the instructions it outputs to get it into your PATH (or you can call it directly from its location)